# Bootstrap v4 - Make User-Card with vertical align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Even though its still alpha, i decided to use bootstrap for the website im curerntly working on.
As an important element of my site, i want to make "business"-cards to display user's basic information, based on the new card class of bootstrap.
Unfortunately i cant get these cards to look exactly the way i want them.

This is how i want them to look like:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgTGn.png)

And this is how it looks so far:
[attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdVEr.png)

Thats my code:

```html
<div class="card user-card" onclick="site.load_content('user_profile', 'cteoa3n');">
   <div class="card-block">
      <div class="user-card-image d-inline-block"><img src="/media/profile_pictures/cteoa3n/1472677543.jpg" class="img-circle"></div>
      <div class="user-card-content text-nowrap d-inline-block">
         <h5 class="card-title">Chris Lnrd</h5>
         <div class="card-text">Free User</div>
         <div class="card-text dental-text font-weight-bold">Dental Medicine</div>
         <div class="card-text">Generation 2016 - Group 11</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the scss for it:

```html
$user-card-width: 300px;
$user-card-height: 130px;

.user-card{
  height: $user-card-height;
  width: $user-card-width;
  max-width: $user-card-width;
  overflow: hidden;
  .card-block{
    height: 100%;
  }
  .user-card-image{
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .user-card-content{    
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  :hover{
    background-color: $gray-lightest;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

As you can see, i can't get the profile picture to be centererd vertically. And if I manage, the content of the card is not centered.
Also, i wonder what a good solution would be to fit the user name inside the card, even if its long, because as soon as its length exceeds the fixed width of the card, it screws up the entire layout.

Hope somebody has an idea how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved you have to use div table style

```
.card.user-card {
      display: table;
}
.card-block {
      display: table-row;
}
.user-card-image {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.user-card-content {
      display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
```

Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/xq7hwvdg/

Comment: thank you for your help. yet i found a different solution, see in my response

Answer (score 0):

Ali's answer made me experiment more and i finally managed, yet making card-block wasnt the solution since it leads to problems when it comes to filling the whole width of the card. maybe it would have worked if i set % width values for the table cells.

the problem seemed to have been the pre-set padding of .card-block, i had to overwrite the top and bottom paddings. then table and table-cells behaved as expected (without using a table-row).

```html
$user-card-width: 300px;
$user-card-height: 130px;

.user-card{
  height: $user-card-height;
  width: $user-card-width;
  max-width: $user-card-width;
  overflow: hidden;
  .card-block{
    padding: 0rem 1.25rem;
  }
  .user-card-image{
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: $user-card-height;
  }
  .user-card-content{    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: $user-card-height;
  }
  :hover{
    background-color: $gray-lightest;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```